# How to return a list to view after foreach in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this code where I am iterating over objects using `foreach` loop

```cs
 public ActionResult userDocs()
 {
           
    var user = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["UserName"].Value);
    var role = db.userdetails.FirstOrDefault(s => s.UserName == user).FullName;
    var test = "kokulchellamuthu1programmer";
            
    var find = db.ApplySchedule.Where(x => x.CC.Contains(test)).ToList();
            
    foreach(var i in find)
    {
        var res = db.docinfo.Where(z => z.RequestID == i.BookingID).ToList();
    }

    return View(res);
}
```

Now I want to return the `res` variable to `view` in order to display matching downloadable documents to the user, I am unable to return it to the view as the code doesn't compile, can someone please help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Thank You all for your replies, This is the working code ` var find = db.ApplySchedule.Where(x => x.CC.Contains(role)).ToList();
          

            var res = new List<DocInfo>();
            foreach (var i in find)
            {

                var mm = db.docinfo.Where(z => z.RequestID == i.BookingID).ToList();
                res.AddRange(mm);` I did as @Matt U suggested and it worked, again thank you everyone for spending your valuable time helping me,it means a lot to me.

Comment: please don't forget to mark the appropriate answer as the answer to your question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've defined the `res` variable inside the `foreach` block so it's inaccessible in your `return res;` statement. Lift the `res` out of there, so it'd look like this:

```c#
// Replace DocInfo with the correct type name of the db.docinfo model
var res = new List<DocInfo>();

foreach (var i in find)
{
    var entities = db.docinfo.Where(z => z.RequestID == i.BookingID).ToList();
    res.AddRange(entities);
}

return View(res);
```

However, I think you don't even really need the `foreach`. You may be able to just do:

```c#
var res = db.docinfo.Where(z => find.Any(f => f.BookingID == z.RequestID)).ToList();
```

If that results in an invalid operation exception or similar then the first part of the answer should still resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much,First part of your answer did the job. But just out of curiosity before your answer I tried `List<DocInfo> mm = new List <DocInfo>();  with  var mm = db.docinfo.Where(z => z.RequestID == i.BookingID).ToList();` inside foreach loop but it on ly returned 3 matching values but only one out them was stored in the list and sent to view, i thought lists can hold multiple values when used like that.Thank you so much for saving my day

Comment: If you're assigning the result of the `ToList()` (e.g. `mm = query.ToList()`) then that makes sense. You're reassigning the value of `mm` with each iteration. Instead you need to append the items of each iteration using `mm.AddRange(sourceList)`, or `mm.Add(aThing)` if appending a single object to the list.

Answer (score 7):

You must define an empty list before Foreach and add that item to the defined list for each item found equal to your condition. According to the code below :

```
 List<string> ids = new List<string>();
 foreach(var i in find)
            {

                var id = db.docinfo.Where(z => z.RequestID == i.BookingID);
                ids.Add(id);
            }
return ids;
```